# CakePHP multiple time and condition with price not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have this query in CakePHP and it is not working. But I have record in db when I remove the inner price condition the it return result but not working with price.

```
SELECT `Car`.`id`, `Car`.`title`, `Car`.`description`, `Car`.`image`, `Car`.`state`, 
    `Car`.`state_code`, `Car`.`city`, `Car`.`zipcode`, `Car`.`person_name`, `Car`.`email`, 
    `Car`.`phone`, `Car`.`mobile`, `Car`.`ad_type`, `Car`.`ad_status`, `Car`.`make`, 
    `Car`.`model`, `Car`.`year`, `Car`.`conditiion`, `Car`.`transmision`, `Car`.`color`, 
    `Car`.`fuel`, `Car`.`body`, `Car`.`doors`, `Car`.`mileage`, `Car`.`price`, 
    `Car`.`accessories`, `Car`.`security`, `Car`.`created`, `Car`.`user_id` 
FROM `portal_Carsnew`.`cars` AS `Car` 
WHERE `Car`.`ad_status` = '1' 
    AND `Car`.`make` = 'Ferrari' 
    AND `Car`.`model` = '458 Italia' 
    AND `Car`.`state` = 'New York' 
    AND `Car`.`city` = 'Albany' AND ((`Car`.`price` < 95000) 
    AND (`Car`.`price` > 0)) 
ORDER BY `Car`.`id` 
desc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: when i remove this part it return results AND ((Car.price < 95000) AND (Car.price > 0))

Comment: what is the data type of price column ?

Answer (score 0):

Use cakephp `find` method to select records from table
Try bellow code

```
$this->Car->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
         'Car.ad_status' => 1,
         'Car.make' => 'Ferrari',
         'Car.model' => '458 Italia',
         'Car.state' => 'New York',
         'Car.city' => 'Albany',
         'Car.price >' =>0,
         'Car.price <' =>95000
       ),
       'order'=> 'id DESC',
       'limit' => 10
 ));
```

Comment: Any one who can help me for this issue

Comment: @rocksall its working for me, check your table entries.

Comment: thank you all who respond me. the query is rite and there is no issue actually i did not but the price.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->Car->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array(
 'and' => array(
                    array('Car.price > ' => 0,
                          'Car.price < ' => 95000
                         ),
     'Car.ad_status' => 1,
     'Car.make' => 'Ferrari',
     'Car.model' => '458 Italia',
     'Car.state' => 'New York',
     'Car.city' => 'Albany',
    )),
   'order'=> 'id DESC',
   'limit' => 10
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$price = array();
$price['Car.price >'] = 0;
$price['Car.price <'] = 95000;

$this->Car->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array_merge($price, 
         array(
             'Car.ad_status' => 1,
             'Car.make' => 'Ferrari',
             'Car.model' => '458 Italia',
             'Car.state' => 'New York',
             'Car.city' => 'Albany',
             'Car.price >' => 0,
             'Car.price <' => 95000
         )
     ),
     'order' => 'Car.id DESC',
     'limit' => 10
));
```

Comment: There is not use of array_merge . it automatic take array in AND condition

Comment: yes, you're right. but he (who asking) said that the basic method is not working properly on it so i'm curiously want to know and then i'll give another way.